# Vincular reputación con stackoverflow.com en inglés

Tags: discusión, reputación

Si el contenido teórico de stackoverflow.com y es.stackoverflow.com es el mismo, ¿por qué es necesario ganar reputación desde cero en la versión en español? ¿Por qué no se vincula el contador de reputación?

Comment: **Esta es solo mi idea, no la idea de StackOverflow como compañía ni la idea de algún empleado de StackOverflow**. Me parece que SOen y SOes son sitios diferentes, por ende no se mezcla la reputación. Adicional a esto, las publicaciones que compartes en un sitio no necesariamente están en el otro, y no tienen la misma percepción de los usuarios de ambas comunidades.

Comment: Me gustaría añadir (Y esto es sólo mi opinión) que al ser una nueva comunidad todos los usuarios empiezan con los mismos privilegios (excepto el +100 si ya se tiene una cuenta activa en otro sitio de SE) por lo que la comunidad crece y se genera por sí sola. Eso a mi me parece genial mantenerlo así.

Comment: Yo empiezo con 100 en cualquier comunidad de SE O_o

Comment: Entonces @LuiggiMendoza hubiera empezado hasta arriba de la lista.. mmm... no seria justo. jaja.

Comment: La reputación mide los aportes de un usuario en un determinado sitio. Son sitios separados, mediciones separadas. Adema tienes tu Flair global que incluye todos los sitios que tienes mas de 200 de reputacion, Este es el tuyo, http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/5435182.png te muestro, por ejemplo este otro que incluye varios sitios http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3035018.png

Comment: Si te interesa, a este perfil accedes desde tu perfil de usuario, tocas el link que dice "perfil de la red" arriba a la derecha y te lleva a una pagina desde donde accedes a toda la informacion desde una vision global de la red.